# What is the difference between idParam, idProperty and clientIdProperty

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am curios about the implementations of the `idProperty` one in the model and one in the reader
 and then a `idParam` for the proxy and a `clientIdProperty` on the model

How do we I use them in a right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you get this as a response from the server:

```
{data: [{userid: 1234, username: "foo"}, {userid: 1235, username: "bar"}]}
```

so in your UserModel you will have [`idProperty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty)`: "userid"` this will tell ExtJS which field to use for functions like `getId(), getById()`. You could also define this in the reader to share between some models, but usually you should define the `idProperty` in the model.

[`idParam`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-idParam) seems very unclear to me, it is used only 2 time in the whole framework. is only used to modify the request id parameter send to the server. I don't think this is a parameter you will ever need to change.

[`clientIdProperty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-clientIdProperty) is needed for create operations if `proxy.batchActions == true`. For example: `model.clientIdProperty = "extid"` this will send to the server if we create 2 users:

```
{data: [
    {extid: "ext-user-1", username: "foo"},
    {extid: "ext-user-2", username: "bar"}
]}
```

server response:

```
{data: [
    {extid: "ext-user-1", userid: 1234, username: "foo"},
    {extid: "ext-user-2", userid: 1235, username: "bar"}
]}
```

this will tell ExtJS how to map the server ids to the pre-generated ext ids.

(if `clientIdProperty` is null, ExtJS assumes the same order of request and response for the mapping)